# HTTP listener in Mono does not read HTTP request

Tags: c#, linux, http, mono, listener

I wrote a HTTP listener app in C#/Mono that runs on Raspberry Pi. If I send a HTTP request with Postman from my PC, the request does not reach the Raspberry Pi or the listener does not read it. In other words, a breakpoint in ShowRequestData() never gets hit.

However, if I run the app on my PC (with Mono or NET debugger), it works. My code:

```
httpListenerWorker.DoWork += HttpListenerWorker_DoWork;
        httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/");
        try
        {
            httpListener.Start();
            httpListenerWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Could not start HTTP listener");
        } 

private static void HttpListenerWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            httpContext = httpListener.GetContext();
            httpRequestString = HTTP.ShowRequestData(httpContext.Request);
            if (httpRequestString != "")
            {
                messageReceived = true;
                threadWaitHandle.Set();
            }
        }
    }
public static string ShowRequestData(HttpListenerRequest request)
    {
        if (!request.HasEntityBody)
        {
            return "";
        }
        Stream body = request.InputStream;
        Encoding encoding = request.ContentEncoding;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(body, encoding);

        string s = "";
        s = reader.ReadToEnd();
        body.Close();
        reader.Close();

        return s;
    }
```

I've tried opening port 8080 using iptables, but with no success:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 --jump ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 --jump ACCEPT
iptables-save
```

**Is it a problem with the code? Is there a configuration I need to make on the Raspberry Pi?**

Comment: I doubt you'd need output on port 8080.. but what do you see in the iptables log?

Comment: @BugFinder I little help on how to do that would be appreciated. I've tried this https://tecadmin.net/enable-logging-in-iptables-on-linux/# , and when opening the log I see a continuously updating flow of messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out the problem. It seems I had to write the exact IP of the Raspberry Pi:

```
httpListener.Prefixes.Add("http://" + Helpers.GetLocalIP() + ":8080/");
```

Comment: You asked it to only listen on 127.0.0.1 so it did